# Angular pagination using bootstrap. Slice of undefined. Remote data

Tags: angularjs, undefined, slice, pagination

I've tried setting up pagination for my projetct using Bootstrap UI.

I'm trying to fetch data, taken from an API I made.

I'm currently using uiRouter and I set up a HTML page, where my items are rendered

```
        .state('home', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'partials/galerija.html',
        controller: function($scope, Picture) {
            $scope.filteredPictures = []
                ,$scope.currentPage = 1
                ,$scope.numPerPage = 18
                ,$scope.maxSize = 5;


            Picture.get('')
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.pictures = data;
                })

            $scope.numPages = function () {
                return Math.ceil($scope.pictures.length / $scope.numPerPage);
            };

            $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredPictures = $scope.pictures.slice(begin, end);
            });
        }
    })
```

Picture.get() function successfuly fetches data and I can see it, however $scope.pictures are undefined when I try to slice them. What could be possibly wrong?

I see list of my items when my page is loaded, it's just pagination that doesn't want to work.

Thanks in advance and if more details are needed, feel free to ask.

I edited one plunker, which I used as an example and set $scope.todos as data I get from my api. It works here as intended, however not in my system.

Comment: `Picture.get()` is async. Are you trying to `.slice()` before the `Picture.get()` request is complete? At the time you are slicing, `$scope.pictures` might not actually be set.

Comment: Thank you. I really missed that.

Example works here: [on this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2VbWsUPt6GUVSiaSHUQ?p=preview)

However in my project I'm still getting error cause of pagination div, which sits in HTML file.

http://i.imgur.com/F2OYKXg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your code and the plunker is the contents of the `success` function.

Try modifying your code like so:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'partials/galerija.html',
    controller: function($scope, Picture) {
        $scope.filteredPictures = [], $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.numPerPage = 18, $scope.maxSize = 5;


        Picture.get('').success(function(data) {
            $scope.pictures = data;

            $scope.numPages = function() {
                return Math.ceil($scope.pictures.length / $scope.numPerPage);
            };

            $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage),
                    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredPictures = $scope.pictures.slice(begin, end);
            });

        });
    }
});
```

You'll notice that the `.slice()` call is now occurring synchronously after `$scope.pictures = data;` occurs.

Comment: Thank you. I made this aswell, however in my project pagination bar seems not to be loading for some unknown reasons. Methods are undefined. This is the [result](http://prntscr.com/3n32jg). Can it be cause of uiRouter?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas ah, if the problem goes beyond the code above, try running your code with the development (unminified) versions of those vendor scripts. You'll have to set some breakpoints and do some detective work to figure out what the true issue is. Just a hypothesis, but maybe its the format of your `data`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be that?

I created a copy of my data, that is returned in my api. I named it data.json and read it in plunker. Data is loaded and paginated in plunker just fine. I'll try loading full angular version to locate bug.

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2VbWsUPt6GUVSiaSHUQ?p=preview)

Comment: It was bootstrap javascript file causing errors. Upgrading it fixed everything.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas nice. glad it was a simpler fix than we thought haha.